# how insert data from multi select in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, multi-select

how insert data from  multi select in mysql

or make array  string like ->...

```
 $arr =array('a'=>'1','b'=>'3','c'=>'5');
```

out put like 
1,3,5
to insert all values in one column like
$sth = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `data` SET category = $arr  where id = 1");

```
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label for="area" class="control-label">Rank</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="number" name="rank" id="area" value="<?= $this->detali->rank ?>" />
                    </div>
                </div>





                <div class="control-group">
                    <label for="artist " class="control-label">Artist</label>
                    <?php
                    $art = explode(',', $this->detali->artist);
                    ?>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <select multiple="multiple" id="my-select" name="artist[]" class='multiselect'>
                            <?php 
                            foreach ($this->artist as $artist) { ?>
                                <option value="<?= $artist->artist_id ?>" <?php

                                            foreach ($art as $value) {

                                if (!(strcmp("$artist->artist_id", htmlentities($value, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8')))) {
                                    echo "SELECTED";
                                }                                                    

                                            }

                                ?>><?= $artist->artist_name ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

how to get data from `$_POST['artist'] (artist[])`

```
like  1,5,6
```

not array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$arr =array('a'=>'1','b'=>'3','c'=>'5');
echo implode(",", array_values($arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you're wanting to take data in an array like

```
array(3) {
    [0] => 'one',
    [1] => 'two',
    [2] => 'three'
}
```

and have it output in a string like

```
one,two,three
```

If that's the case, you can use PHP's `implode` function:

```
<?php
    $my_array = array('one', 'two', 'three);
    $my_string = implode(',', $array);
?>
```

Documentation for `implode` can be found at http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php